# How to access data from an array of strings? C

Tags: c, arrays

I am having lot of problems with my `C` code. I am saving data into my `array` with this function:

```
/**
* Insert Data into array
* @param char[] pointer
*/
void insertData(char **data) {
    int i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      data[i] = malloc(10000);
      printf("Nombre del paciente %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%s", &data[i][0]);
      printf("Habitacion: ");
      scanf("%s", &data[i][1]);
      printf("Cama: ");
      scanf("%s", &data[i][2]);
      free(*data);
    }
}
```

My variable data is : `char data[2][3];`

And I'm trying to show this data with the next function:

```
void mostrarResultados(char **data) {
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("\n");
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%c ", data[i,j], **data);
     }
    }
}
```

But the console `return` me weird characters: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

To these functions I am calling them this way:

```
    //First menu
    do{
        switch (option){
            case 1:
                insertData(data);
                setFirstTime(false);
                mostrarResultados(data);
                break;
            case 2:
                exit(0);
                break;
        }
    } while (option == 0);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better can use a struct to hold the data. Someting like

```
Struct data {
   char nombre[32];
   Char habitacion[32];
   char cama[32];
}
```

And malloc the struct malloc(sizeof(struct data) * nr of struct you want)

Comment: Yes, but I have to declare 20 structs new, because I am doing an example with an array[2] but in the future i want to do with 20, and I have to do 20  struct Data Data1; etc...

Comment: But you can make an array of structs

Answer (score 0):

When programming in C or C++, you *must* enable compiler warnings, understand them and fix them properly. Everything else is irresponsible.

In this case, the compiler will warn about the printf call, since you are passing the wrong type (and number) of arguments.